# Reshape a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Although I have tried `np.reshape` and `transpose`, I am not getting the desired output.

I have a numpy array that looks like this:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 1, 2, 2],[1, 1, 2, 2],[1, 1, 2,2]])
>>> a
array([[1, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 2]])
```

I want the following:

```
>>> b = np.array([[1, 2],[1,2],[1,2],[1, 2],[1,2],[1,2]])
>>> b
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 2]])
```

The best I can do is in four lines of code:

```
e, f = np.hsplit(a,2)
e = e.reshape(np.size(e))
f = f.reshape(np.size(f))
b = np.vstack((e,f)).T
```

Can someone provide me with the pythonic way to reshape an array in this manner?

Comment: Would  `b = np.reshape(a,(6,2),'F')` be enough?

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear exactly what you are looking for by only using 1s and 2s in the example. Please use letters or unique numbers so the mapping is clearer.

I was able to do some jiggling to make it work but I'm not 100% if this is the mapping you want. See the steps below:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 1, 2, 2],[1, 1, 2, 2],[1, 1, 2,2]])

array([[1, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 2]])


>>> a.reshape(6,2)

array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 2]])

>>> a.reshape(6,2).transpose()

array([[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]])

>>> a.reshape(6,2).transpose().reshape(6,2)

array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 2]])
```